# How to flatten a list in spark rdd?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD(Long, util.List[Foo]) which I want to flatten on the list to look like RDD(Long, Foo) and then eventually call a getCode method which is a part of the Foo. Here is my approach so far

```
val test = source
  .filter(x => x.getFooList != null)
  .map(x => (x.getFooList, x.getId))
  .map{
    case(foo, id) => foo.toArray().map(foo => (foo, id))
  }
```

*ideally I would like to have the id at the first position*

This method works. However to toArray method converts it from Foo to AnyRef. I cannot call the getCode method on AnyRef. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - if you want to *flatten* your RDD you'll have to use `flatMap` and not `map`. Second, if you want the "id" to come first - place it first in the tuple you're building for each item. And third - since your source RDD contains `java.util.List`s, you'll have to convert them (can be done implicitly with the right import) to Scala collections:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ // import to get implicit conversion 

val test: RDD[(Long, Foo)] = source
 .filter(x => x.getFooList != null)
 .map(x => (x.getFooList, x.getId))
 .flatMap { // use flatMap
    case (foo, id) => foo.map(f => (id, f)) // switch the order
  }
```

Comment: `JavaConversions` are not recommended and deprecated in Scala 2.12. Use `JavaConverters` please: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5109/files

Answer (score 1):

convert `util.List` to **scala** `List` can solve this issue:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
...
case(foo, id) => foo.asScala.map(foo => (foo, id))
...
```